# Docker resource management and runtime configuration

Tags: docker

I am trying to setup docker container with centOS and I need to make runtime changes in its configuration - to change for example memory, or disc size limitations. Is that possible? I saw it is possible to do this with vagrant, but I don't want to use it. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How to limit the disk size of container : https://github.com/snitm/docker/blob/master/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper/README.md

Attention : it's a general option that will affect all your container.

How to limit runtime memory : http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-cpu-and-memory